# Google Drive ID versus Google Apps Script Deployment ID

Tags: google-apps-script

When I want to publish a script it generates a deploy link. Is there any relation between the file id in Drive and the deploy link of apps script?

I am trying to find a relation between those to automate things further so apps scripts in drive in a folder get found and executed.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

no there is no relation. if you find one it can get broken in the future as is not documented.

consider instead keeping a manual mapping maybe in a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, there is no relationship between the various unique IDs assigned to objects in Google Drive that we can exploit programmatically.

I have observed that IDs sometimes have similar substrings in them. For example:

```
// Script ID:
//                                 1b5-wm5A9iBOtK2sk8nn0uorRJUeVavJdNnaouYijMntrwArGVT------
// Public WebApp URL:
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyopDKeOz8fcNU2Zmpt_BKJqZwi_BRtaHYV6N6Q5Z4L7-----/exec
//                                 ^^^^^^
// Dev WebApp URL:
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxmMhxBGo5fuVBHHIAMaT1lKlrmMic9aaacZ_-----/dev
//                                 ^^^^^^
```

While the first 6 characters in the two WebApp URLs match in this example, there is no other repetition, nor any repeat of substrings from the Script ID. (The trailing `-`s were added to obfuscate the real IDs.)